# Run bash scripts from python. MAC OS

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run scripts for `python in MAC OS.`

I was unable to run scripts that run `Bash.sh scripts`, any one here have an idea about how can I run `bash.sh` From python in Mac OS.

Thanks you for any help :)!

(This is the scripts:

```
Called: RunScript.sh, and I need to run it from Python Script.)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does os.system not work?

```
import os
os.system("/path/to/script.sh")
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you would use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

The questions become:

- Do you intend to capture output from this script?
- Do you intend to feed input into it?
- Does it need to interact with the user via the terminal (that Python is using)?
- Do need to capture and or deal with error messages or error codes (return values)?

Comment: Hey Jim, sorry for digging into this (very) old thread. But here I have the third use case in your list. Does `os.system()` open a terminal where it runs the shell/bash script? Does `subprocess.Popen()` opens a terminal window to show what the script is doing? because my script (shell/bash) has some `sudo` commands, and the users should be able to enter in their password when prompted. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @PSSolanki, opening a terminal from within a Python script for password processing is almost certainly a terrible idea.

*sudo* offers a *-S* (*--stdin*) option.  So you could use the Python **getpass** module to prompt for and receive the password, and can you feed it into sudo's standard input stream (on a line by itself) the *Popen()* object's stdin attribute (which is a file like object, using *subprocess.PIPE* option.)

Comment: Appreciate the input. I saw the `-S` flag through pycharm prompts. I'll try that :)